# How do I enforce unique user names in Flask?

Tags: python, sql, web-applications, flask

I'm a complete beginner to Flask and I'm starting to play around with making web apps.

I have a hard figuring out how to enforce unique user names. I'm thinking about how to do this in SQL, maybe with something like `user_name text unique on conflict fail`, but then how to I catch the error back in Python?

Alternatively, is there a way to manage this that's built in to Flask?

Comment: Maybe you can use `try...except...` to catch exception while add new record to database.

Comment: Are SQL errors automatically caught?

Comment: no. Please look at @cwallenpoole's answer, you can catch exceptions while you're trying to commit to database.

Answer (score 6):

That entirely depends on your database layer. Flask is very specifically *not* bundled with a specific ORM system, though SQL Alchemy is recommended. The good news is that SQL Alchemy has a unique constraint.

Here's how it might work:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, InvalidRequestError
engine = #my engine
session = Session() # created by sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)

# then later...

user = User()
user.name = 'Frank'
session.add(user)

try:
    session.commit()
    print 'welcome to the club Frank'
except InvalidRequestError:
    print 'You are not Frank. Impostor!!!'
```

Run the part after "then later" twice. The first time you'll get a welcome message, the second time you won't.

---

**Addendum**: The closest thing that Flask has to a [default authentication framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/31/) [simply stores users in a `dict` by username](https://github.com/shanewholloway/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/contrib/authdigest.py). The way to check to enforce uniqueness is by manually testing eg.

```
if username in digest_db:
    raise Exception('HEY! "{}" already exists! \
                     You can\'t do that'.format(username))
digest_db.add_user(username, password)
```

or overriding `RealmDigestDB` to make sure that it checks before adding:

```
class FlaskRealmDigestDB(authdigest.RealmDigestDB):
    def add_user(self, user, password):
        if user in self:
            raise AttributeError('HEY! "{}" already exists! \
                                  You can\'t do that'.format(user))
        super(FlaskRealmDigestDB, self).add_user(user, password)

    def requires_auth(self, f):
        # yada yada
```

or overriding `RealmDigestDB`, and making it return something which does not allow duplicate assignment. eg.

```
class ClosedDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, name, val):
       if name in self and val != self[name]:
          raise AttributeError('Cannot reassign {} to {}'.format(name, val))
    super(ClosedDict, self).__setitem__(name,val)


class FlaskRealmDigestDB(authdigest.RealmDigestDB):
    def newDB():
        return ClosedDict()

    def requires_auth(self, f):
        # yada yada
```

I put this here as an addendum because that class does not persist data in any way, if you're planning on extending `authdigest.RealmDigestDB` anyway you should use something like SQLAlchemy as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLAlchemy.It's a plug-in